# Socket connection broke with pyignite

Tags: python, pom.xml, ignite

I try to connect to Ignite instance which runs as dependency of Java app. 
There is part of pom.xml (... dots indicates other props).

```
<properties>
    ...
    <ignite-version>2.7.0</ignite-version>
    ...
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Then in python I try to connect to client:

main.py

```
from pyignite import Client


client = Client()
client.connect("127.0.0.1",47100)

# it brokes on any other command too
client.create_cache('my_cache')
```

Last command throws `OSError: Socket connection broken.`

Is Ignite somehow secured to don't allow other connections than from Java app? Sould I use separate installation of ignite cluster? Or is it some error in connection code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely not use port `47100`. The default client connector port is `10800`.